# Label in bold with line break when subscript is included

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-breaks, subscript

I need to plot a label in bold which include a subscript. I tried the expression

```
bquote(atop(‘Value’ ~(k"^~r^-2*")~, (old data)))
```

but with no result. I want the phrase old data at the second row. Any ideas on how to change my command? Is there any obvious mistake that I cannot see?

```
df=1:100
df=data.frame(1:100)
df$z=df$X1.100*0.3
names(df)=c("k","f")

ggplot(df,aes(x=k, y=f))+ geom_point()+labs(x="k",y=bquote(atop(‘Value’ ~(k"^~r^-2*")~, (old data))))
```

Comment: Please show a reproducable example

Comment: You could either use the `str_wrap` package or add `\n` values directly with `gsub`. For bolding, the option `fontface="bold"` should work.

Comment: @Choubi the \n didn't work for me. I managed to do this with > ggplot(df,aes(x=k, y=f))+ geom_point()+labs(x="k",y=bquote(atop("Value(k"^~r^-2*")", "(old data)")))
but the problem is that it is not in bold. How to use the fontface you mentioned in my example?

Comment: What do you want to be bold?  If you want the whole label in bold, use `bold` around the `atop` statement, i.e., `bquote(bold(atop(...)))`

Comment: Yes I have already done it with your way. Thank you for your response @aosmith it was exactly what I wanted.